# Open image in image viewer then save it to a folder with new name

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want some code to open an image in 'ImageViewer' from client's hard disc. After that I want to save that image with a new name inside a folder.

I used this code to upload a picture from the client's machine.

```
    Dim open As New OpenFileDialog
    open.Multiselect = False
    open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp"
    Dim chck As Boolean = open.ShowDialog()
    If chck = True Then
        Dim filepath As String = open.FileName
        Dim img_source As ImageSource = New BitmapImage(New Uri(filepath))
        img_viewer.Source = imgsr
    End If
```

But now I want to know how to save that image with a new name inside a folder.

Comment: Why not just copy the file by [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx)?

Comment: Please tell me how to use file.copy ? To save image with a new name

Comment: Well, it has two parameters, the source file path and the destination file path.